# How to compare a variable string with a string in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to do this:

```
{% ifnotequal slider.title "" %}
<div class="dev-caption-big">
{{ slider.titulo }}
</div>
{% endifnotequal %}
```

But this should not create the div because the variable string (slider.titulo) is empty.

How to compare?

Comment: You are checking the value of `slider.title` but printing the value of `slider.titulo`?

Comment: Just i little mistake. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better check than what you have now, try this one:

```
{% if slider.titulo|length > 0 %}
   <div class="dev-caption-big">
       {{ slider.titulo }}
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It will create the div if there is a value in the variable, even if its a bunch of spaces, like _"      "_.

Comment: I change 0 to 1, and still creates. And its not have a bunch of spaces.

Comment: What is the HTML source created? Can you update your question with that?

Comment: It creates the <div class="dev-caption-big"></div>